# PHP Inputs that hold value for my CSS page

Tags: php, css, ajax

Im not really sure if I am explaining this right, but I want to make my CSS page updatable via a PHP Form with Text inputs, and radio boxes. How does one go about doing this? ANy links or info would be very helpful.

Lemme explain as good as possible. I am thinking that first I will need a form with various inputs that passes values (post/get) to my css page. But I will need to make sure those values in the php form stick, so the next time I make changes to it, they will have the vaues from my css sheet as well. Would this be best to do with ajax?

Comment: `"I want to make my CSS [file] updatable via a PHP Form"` - could you explain why?

Comment: I am going to be adding a lot of elements to it, and it would be much easier to do it this way.

Comment: Why AJAX anyways? You would be looking for a database or something, right?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is make a php file called style.php and add on top `header("content-type:text/css");`. Fetch information from the database and put it in the css file.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a SSH access you could use nano (pico) to edit the CSS file.
Here, http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=672977, **risoknop** gives an example of PHP text editor, using a form to edit a text file. It's on the end of the post.